# Serving static files in django for image processing

Tags: django

Can anyone please explain how to serve static files in django,  keeping in mind, i also have to fetch images from the location of hosting and then resize them,  after that send to my template..

Can't find any YouTube video or documents that explains it clearly

Comment: Can you explain what was unclear about the Django documentation about static files?

Answer (score 0):

You have to set up your STATIC direction as it's shown here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/howto/static-files/

Answer (score 0):

Go through the official doc. Very interesting.
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/howto/static-files/